# how to input data into KERAS python?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, data-science

In keras fit function

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16)
```

How should I input the data when i have more columns?

I want to input image, and detect object of class 1 on it. So the output is `(x, y, width, height)`

The input image should be `416 x 416 x 3` and output matrix should be `13x13x4` so i want to detect up to 169 objects.

Should the

```
X_train
```

variable be loaded set of images ( so it will be 4 dimensional array of N x 416 x 416 x 3 )

and

```
y_train
```

be 2D array of N x 4 , where 4 represents ( x ,y , width, height ) ?

If so what do i have to pass in `validation_data` arguments?

I am really confused.

Comment: I am not sure what level of depth you are, but the link below should get you started - https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: I honestly don't understand your use case. What are you trying to classify? Objects? Or are you trying to define the (x,y)-coordinates? Or maybe the height or the width? However in Keras you can input the Array of [N x 416 x 416 x 3]. The validation set is used to get the actual loss and accuracy between every step/epoch. It is used so that  the algorithm doesn't need to take some samples from your training set.

Comment: I am trying do detect object on the image ( so basicly its x and y coordinates and width height so i can draw rectangle over it ). If i understood it correctly the y_train should be labels, in my case it should be x y width and height cooridantes?

Answer (score 1):

The test (validation) data should have the same shape as the training data: the `X` must be "feedable" into the network and `y` must be "comparable" to the output of the network, no matter if it's for training or testing. So if

```
X_train.shape == (N, 416, 416, 3)
y_train.shape == (N, 169, 4)
```

... then the test data

```
X_test.shape == (M, 416, 416, 3)
y_test.shape == (M, 169, 4)
```

Here I assume you want to detect `169` objects at once per training instance. This number depends on the data you have, traditional datasets contain much fewer objects per image. Up to `10` objects would result in `(N, 10, 4)` output shape.

There's a [nice tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-neural-networks-a4e2c46b4491) on object detection with keras (here's [the code](https://github.com/jrieke/shape-detection/blob/master/color-multiple-shapes.ipynb)), which can serve as an example.